# Why is not possible to update dynamically the HTML DOM structure when `<!DOCTYPE html>` is specified?

Tags: html

I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Clear a Timer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        var theTimer, xPosition = 0, theImage;

        function doTimer() {
            theImage = document.getElementById("courseraLogo");
            xPosition = xPosition + 1;
            theImage.style.left = xPosition;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="theTimer = setInterval(doTimer, 50)">
    <img src="../img/coursera.png" id="courseraLogo"
         style="position:absolute; left:0">
    <button onclick="clearTimeout(theTimer);">
        Stop!
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is supposed to move an image from left to right at an interval of 50ms. It does not work if a specify the `DOCTYPE` tag: the image does not move. Why this is happening? Is there any compatibility issue related to the HTML version? Or do I need to use a similar method to `setInterval` compatible with HTML5?

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @ochi There is not any error in the console.

Comment: I have updated the line `theImage.style.left = xPosition + "px";` and it works with the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Ah! there you have it....  simple... post it as answer and mark it :)

Comment: :) HTML5 is more strict!

Comment: what browser are you using? - I tried with and without the `DOCTYPE` on chrome and it didn't work for me - maybe it's the browser/html5 combo?

Comment: @ochi with this code it is working correctly! http://pastebin.com/stXFW4ap

Comment: Sorry, I meant I was not able to reproduce the original error (the fix works) - so I am wondering if it's a browser issue (as opposed to an HTML5 thing) in other words, it could a browser-support issue for HTML5 (or lack of) instead

Comment: Have you tried using the code listed in the question?

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the units when setting `style.left`:

`theImage.style.left = xPosition + "px";`

This isn't strictly speaking an HTML5 thing. Omitting the units works only if you include no doctype at all: including an HTML4 doctype such as `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` will also cause your script to fail unless you include the units.

(I tested this in current versions of Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on OS X; all three behaved identically.)

Comment: I think that HTML5 is more strict respect to the units.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation: I spent more than hour trying to detect the error/inconsistency.